# Handle wildcard generic list with Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb, wildcard

I have following data model :

```
class A{
 private List<? extends B> bList;

//getter and setter
}

//class B is some other domain class.
```

currently I am getting error like

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class
>   com.ticketmaster.platform.search.web.model.UserAccount nor any of its
>   super class is known to this context.

How can I handle this with jaxb?